# How do I solve this problem on maximizing sum modulo a given number?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am stuck in solving this math problem. I need to maximize 
$$
(a_1\cdot x_1 + a_2\cdot x_2 + a_3\cdot x_3 + \dots + a_n\cdot x_n) \mathbin{\mathrm \%} b.
$$
Here $a_i$ and $b$ are given and $x_i$ can be any nonnegative integer.

Comment: Where is this problem from? What have you tried?

Comment: I believe this question is slightly disingenuous, as it directly relates to a problem in an ongoing Codechef Contest. Problem reference: https://www.codechef.com/APRIL19B/problems/SJ1

Answer (score 1):

**Tl;dr**: The maximum value is
$$
b- \gcd(a_1,\dots,a_n,b).
$$
When all $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are $0$ modulo $b$, this value is $0$, and any coefficients can be used (eg. $x_i = 0$). Otherwise the coefficients are
$$
x_i = \left( y_i\cdot \frac {b- \gcd(a_1,\dots,a_n,b)}{\gcd(a_1,\dots,a_n) \mathbin{\mathrm\%} b} \right) \mathbin{\mathrm\%} b,
$$
where $y_i$ are such that
$$
\gcd(a_1,\dots,a_n) = a_1 y_1 + a_2  y_2 + a_3 y_3 + .... + a_n y_n.
$$

Now the explanation.

---

1. First, observe that, modulo $b$, integral linear combinations of $a_1, \dots, a_n$ are exactly multiples of the greatest common divisor of those numbers, so we'll need to find the maximum multiple modulo $b$ of that. Denote for brevity:
   $$
   g := \gcd (a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n).
   $$
   Of course every linear combination is a multiple of $g$. On the other hand, by the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#The_case_of_more_than_two_numbers)/[Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity#For_three_or_more_integers), $g$ is actually the value of some combination:
   $$
   g = a_1 y_1 + a_2  y_2 + a_3 y_3 + .... + a_n y_n
   $$
   (see a clarification in a note at the end). Here some of $y_i$ are negative, however, if considered modulo $b$, we can use modulos of $y_i$, which are nonnegative:
   $$
   g \stackrel{\mathbin{\mathrm\%} b}= g \mathbin{\mathrm\%} b \stackrel{\mathbin{\mathrm\%} b}=  a_1 (y_1\mathbin{\mathrm\%} b) + a_2  (y_2\mathbin{\mathrm\%} b) + .... + a_n (y_n\mathbin{\mathrm\%} b)
   $$
   or in other notation
   $$
   g  \stackrel{\bmod b}\equiv g\bmod b \stackrel{\bmod b}\equiv a_1 (y_1\bmod b) + a_2  (y_2\bmod b) + .... + a_n (y_n\bmod b).
   $$
2. Now, the multiples of $g$ considered modulo $b$ are exactly the same as the multiples of $\gcd(g,b)$ modulo $b$, so exactly the same as integral linear combinations of $a_1, \dots, a_n$ modulo $b$. This is because for some $k$, $l$, $m$:

   - $\gcd(g,b) = kg + lb$,  so  for any $r$: $r\cdot\gcd(g,b) = rkg + rlb$, hence
     $$r\cdot\gcd(g,b) \stackrel{\mathbin{\mathrm\%} b}= (rk)g,$$
   - $g = m\gcd(g,b)$, so for any $r$
     $$r\cdot g = (rm)\gcd(g,b).$$

Note that
$$
\gcd(g,b) =  \gcd (a_1, a_2, \dots a_n, b),
\gcd(g,b) = \gcd(g \mathbin{\mathrm\%} b, b)
$$

3. The maximum multiple of $\gcd(g,b)$ modulo $b$ (and hence **the maximum linear combination of $a_1, \dots, a_n$**) is
   $$
   b - \gcd(g,b) ,
   $$
   (see also the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3177895/what-is-maximum-value-of-a-b-mod-c-where-a-and-c-are-known)). Now, if $g \mathbin{\mathrm\%} b = 0$, this means that all $a_i$ are $0$ modulo $b$, that is divisible by $b$ -- then the formula for the maximum value is correct and we can take any linear combination. If $g \mathbin{\mathrm\%} b \neq 0$,  we can rewrite
   $$
   b - \gcd(g,b) =  \left(\frac {b- \gcd(g,b)}{g \mathbin{\mathrm\%} b} \right) \cdot (g \mathbin{\mathrm\%} b).
   $$
   so we multiply the linear combination with $y_i$ by this fraction:
   \begin{align*}
   b - \gcd(g,b) 
   &\stackrel{\mathbin{\%}b}=\left(\frac {b- \gcd(g,b)}{g \mathbin{\mathrm\%} b} \right) \cdot \bigg( a_1 (y_1\mathbin{\mathrm\%}b) + a_2  (y_2\mathbin{\mathrm\%}b) + .... + a_n (y_n\mathbin{\mathrm\%} b)\bigg)
   \\
   &\stackrel{\mathbin{\%}b}=\sum _{i=1}^n a_i\cdot \left(\frac {b- h}{g \mathbin{\mathrm\%} b} \right)\cdot (y_i\mathbin{\mathrm\%}b)
   \end{align*}
   where
   $$
   h = \gcd(g,b) = \gcd (a_1, a_2, \dots a_n, b). 
   $$
   Your desired linear combination is considered modulo $b$, so we can modulo the coefficients as well. In other words, as the coefficients we can take
   $$
   x_i = \left[ y_i\left(\frac {b- h}{g \mathbin{\mathrm\%} b} \right) \right] \mathbin{\mathrm\%} b.
   $$

---

Edit: The greatest common divisor of more than three numbers may be calculated recursively:
$$
\gcd(p,q,r) = \gcd\left(\,\gcd(p,q),\,r\right)\\
\gcd (a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n) = \gcd( \dots \gcd(\gcd (a_1, a_2),a_3), \dots, a_n)
$$
Similarly, we calculate the coefficients $y_1, \dots y_n$ recursively: first
$$
\gcd (a_1, a_2) = s^{(1)} a_1 + t^{(1)} a_2,
$$
then
\begin{align}
\gcd (a_1, a_2, a_3) &= \gcd(\gcd (a_1, a_2),a_3)\\
&= s^{(2)} \cdot \gcd (a_1, a_2) + t^{(2)} a_3\\
&= s^{(2)} \cdot (s^{(1)} a_1 + t^{(1)} a_2) + t^{(2)} a_3\\
&= (s^{(2)} s^{(1)}) a_1 + (s^{(2)} t^{(1)}) a_2 + t^{(2)} a_3,
\end{align}
and so on.

Comment: I can use the Euclidean algorithm to determine $y_i$ for every term right?

Comment: After finding $x_i$ corresponding to every $a_i$ , I need to find the sum $a_i \cdot x_i$ and then mod the sum with b, to get the maximum value?

Comment: Re 1) see footnote. 

Re 2) You could, but the maximum value is right there, it's $b - \gcd(a_1,\dots,a_n,b)$. $ \\ $ See recent editions.

Comment: I just need a formula for the maximum value. $b - gcd(a_1, ... , a_n,b)$ doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @DebidasMukherjee Could you give any example?

Comment: @DebidasMukherjee Oh, and what are $a_i$, $b$? Integers? Positive/nonnegative integers?

Comment: $a_i$ and $b$ can be any natural number as high as $10^{18}$ .

Comment: @DebidasMukherjee Thanks, and could you give any example that $b - \gcd(a_1,\dots,a_n,b)$ doesn't work?

Comment: @user661295 It seems ok now. The maximum is still the same, but I've corrected the coefficients $x_i$.