# What is maximum value of $a b\mod c$ , where $a$ and $c$ are known.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, math-software

I need to find maximum value of $a b \mod c$ where values of $a$ and $c$ are given.

Eg: $a = 7 , c= 10 $
    By putting $b = 7$ we get maximum value as $9$.

Comment: If $a$ is a unit in $\Bbb Z/c\Bbb Z$ then the maximum of $ab\ (\text {mod}\ c)$  is definitely $c-1.$

Comment: Can you please explain me in detail. What is Z ?

Comment: $\Bbb Z$ is the set of all integers.

Comment: $\Bbb Z/c \Bbb Z$ is the set of all residue classes of $\Bbb Z$ modulo $c.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$d = \gcd(a,c) \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

By [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that

$$ax + cy = d \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Since $d \mid c$, then $k = \frac{c-d}{d}$ is an integer. Multiplying both sides of \eqref{eq2} by $k$ gives

$$akx + cky = c - d \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

This shows that if $b = kx$ gives $ab \equiv c - d \mod c$. Since $d$ divides $a$ and $c$, it must also divide $ab - mc$ for any integers $b$ and $m$. Since the next larger value than $c - d$ which is a multiple of $d$ is $c$, this shows that $c - d$ is the largest value you are looking for between $0$ and $c-1$, inclusive.

With your particular example, since $\gcd(7,10) = 1$, the largest values is $10 - 1 = 9$, as you've noticed.

Comment: Simpler to exploit the innate *negation* symmetry - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $ $ By Bezout, $\,d :=\gcd(a,c)\,$ is the *least* value of $\,ax\bmod c = ax+cy,\,$ for integers $\,x,y$.

Thus $\, c - d\,$ is the *greatest* value since these values are closed under *negation* $\, n\mapsto c-n \pmod{\! c}$

**Remark** $\ \gcd(a,b)=1\!\iff\! {\rm lcm}(a,b) = ab\,$ is  [analogously provable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921108/242) by exploiting an involution (reflection) *symmetry*, namely cofactor reflection (vs. negation reflection above).